# Automatically Sync system time from hwclock once a day

Tags: time, date

My system time on a ubuntu 16 EC2 instance seems to keep shifting, couple minutes every month, after 4 months they have shifted so far that calls to the AWS api are failing. The hwclock seems fine - not shifted, and restarting the server seems to resolve it (shifts the system time back to correct time, matching hwclock)

Automatically restarting the server once a day seems a bit excessive, so a cron job to automatically sync the system time from the hwclock would be an acceptable patch until i can upgrade the servers to the latest ubuntu in a few months, (which may or may not resolve it, but we will see then).

Comment: Why not set up ntp on the instance? That'll keep track of time for you, without any fuzzy setup.

Comment: it has ntp already.